# How can I use ResultSetMetaData in MySql & Java in order to have info about the tables in the database and the length of the columns?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I use MySql and Java. In order to create a general data inputting program in Java (using SWING) I need information about the number of tables in the database and about the length of the columns. Is it possible to use ResultSetMetaData? I've found only examples regarding column names and column types.
Thank you,
Emil

Comment: Listing the tables and views of a database requires to run a query on its catalog, which is a special set of tables that describes the database itself. It would be useful if you could specify which DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can get it from `DatabaseMetaData`:

**For Example**:

```
java.sql.DatabaseMetaData metaData = con.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = metaData.getColumns(schema, null, "TABLE_NAME", "COLUMN_NAME");
if (rs.next()) {
    int colSize = rs.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE");
}
```

If your read the doc for `getColumns` method, you'll see that the `COLUMN_SIZE` is one of meta columns that its retrieve.

**doc**:

> 1. COLUMN_SIZE int => column size.

Read the full documentation from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: That is the general database metadata, not the result set metadata.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: DatabaseMetaData seems to be correct to know about a table specific information. OP might have inquired about `'ResultsetMetaData'` unknowingly. Though RSMD also can be used, one has to know system tables and may be their column names.

Comment: @Ravinder Good point, I hadn't thought of that.